# Least-Squares Opposite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, projection

Is there an opposite formulation of least-squares projection where the distance between each point–say, $(x_{i}, y_{i})$– and the subspace that it's projected onto (e.g. a line through the origin) is *maximized*? In researching the subject, it seems that the singular value decomposition (SVD) of a matrix is somehow involved, but I couldn't find a clear-cut answer.

Comment: If $V$ is a nontrivial subspace (i.e., it contains at least one nonzero vector) then there are points $v[n] \in V$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ||v[n]||=\infty$.  So the supremum distance from any point $z \notin V$ to the set $V$ is infinity.  In particular for any point $z$ we have for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ $$ \sup_{v \in V}||z-v|| \geq ||z-v[n]||\geq ||v[n]||-||z||$$ where the final inequality is the "reverse triangle inequality." Taking a limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ gives $$ \sup_{v \in V}||z-v||=\infty$$

Comment: Is there a solution that involves the SVD (or maybe principal component analysis)?

Comment: What matrix are you talking about?

Comment: If I was interested in *minimizing* the error between the point and its orthogonal projection onto a subspace, I could use the least-squares algorithm. Maybe the line was of the form $y=ax+b$; I could then plug in my point values $(x_{i}, y_{i})$ and place those values (now coefficients of $a$ and $b$) into a matrix $A$. For least-squares, I would compute $(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b$ to find the vector holding $a$ and $b$. But what if we were interested in which $a$ and $b$ values for $y=ax+b$ produce the *greatest* possible error between the points and the projection? Does that make more sense?

Comment: I thought this might involve PCA as we are interested in maximizing the variance.

Comment: In what sense was my initial comment insufficient?